# Keep music playing while changing orientation

Tags: android, rotation, media

I'm making music player app for Android and i have problem with keeping music playing while i change orientation of phone.

```
    package nori.beta.musicplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import nori.beta.musicplayer.Class.BlurBuilder;
import nori.beta.musicplayer.Fragment.Playlist;
import nori.beta.musicplayer.Fragment.Utilities;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView bg;       // blured backgroud of size of screen
    private ImageView cover;    // small image in center of activity that plays song
    private BlurBuilder blured; // class to blur image for background

    private SeekBar
            progressBar;            // Creating seekbar that show progress of song and allow us scroll and rewind song
    private ImageButton
            play_pause_stopButton;  //on click do 1.play/2.paues/3.stop for all change icon
    private MediaPlayer player; // Player that play music
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); //Handler that help with refreshing progressBar
    private Utilities utils; //Change seconds into min + sec
    ArrayList<File> mySongs; // list of music file
    ArrayList<Song> songsInfo; //list of music file with extract information about them

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // init all GUI staff
        initGUI();
        setButtons();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // init Database and rest of gui staff that need database
        // Here have u data of all file and chosen song and can u make to play song
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        // Image Part
        bg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_background);
        cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
        blured = new BlurBuilder();

        //Buttons
        play_pause_stopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause_stop_button);
        progressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        utils = new Utilities();
        mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        songsInfo = new ArrayList<Song>();
        for (File f : mySongs) {
            songsInfo.add(new Song(f));
        }
        //progressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    }

    private ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
        ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = root.listFiles();

        /**
         * findSongs Search for music file in memory
         *
         * for each file in memory
         * 1.if is that file a folder , then  take all file then give it in method findSongs
         * and with requrency
         * 2.Else if that file end with .mp3 or .wav ,then add to list
         */

        for (File singleFile : files) {
            if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
                al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
                //Log.e("findsongs","Folder");
            } else {
                if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
                    al.add(singleFile);
                    Log.e("FileInfo.GetSong", singleFile.getName().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return al;
    }

    private void setButtons() {
        play_pause_stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //Play/Pause song button clicked
                playSong(0);
            }
        });

        progressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() { //Using progress bar to scrolling song

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar progressBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar progressBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar progressBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) { //When user move progress bar song go to moment that user choosed
                if (player != null && fromUser) {
                    player.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }
            }
        });
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) { //When song ended playing
                playSong(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); //Updating progressBar every 100ms
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { //Updating time of song and progressbar
            long totalDuration = player.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = player.getCurrentPosition();

            // Updating progress bar
            int mCurrentPosition = player.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
            progressBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

        }
    };

    // set it in all changes of the privius songs <#-- Krzysiek -->
    private void setBackground(int i) {
        //setting the back image and cover image to the chosen song
        if (songsInfo.get(i).getBackground() != null) {
            bg.setImageBitmap(blured.blur(this, songsInfo.get(i).getBackground()));
            cover.setImageBitmap(songsInfo.get(i).getBackground());
            Log.i("FileInfo.SetCover", "Set cover of " + songsInfo.get(i).getName());
        }

    }

    public void playSong(int index) {
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(songsInfo.get(index).getPath()); //Getting song with proper index from list
            player.prepare();
            player.start(); //Playing prepared song
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsInfo.get(index).getTitle();
            String songArtist = songsInfo.get(index).getArtist();

            setBackground(index);
            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            play_pause_stopButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(player.getDuration() / 1000);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I tried with

> ```
>     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
> ```

in manifest and it work but only for 1st change from vertical to horizontal orientation. When i change again from horizontal to vertical, same song start from beggining while old is still playing so i have 2 songs played at same moment. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

keep the config changes and add an override to the onconfig...

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
}
```

when the orientation changes the oncreate is called by default , you need to override it like this example or maybe use a singleton as a mediaplayer so it won't create two of them

Comment: I tried overriding it like you wrote but it still start new song when i change from horizontal to vertical.

Comment: try using a flag so it won't re-instanciate the make mediaplayer a global variable and make a new instance of it only if it's null

Comment: I tried         `if(player==null)
            player=new MediaPlayer();` but it still start new another song.

Comment: make a breakpoint  here                                                                                 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) { //When song ended playing
                playSong(0);
            }   and see if it reaches this code when you change orientation

Comment: I made breakpoint in onCompletionListener and tried changing orientation but it didn't break so problem isn't here :/

Comment: try  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"  in the menifest and in the activity try  @Override
            public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

              super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

              if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                  //your code
              } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //your code

              }
            }

Answer (score 0):

It was just stupid but i just make player static. It helped and now it dont create additional instances

Answer (score 0):

When you orientate your device, it redraw your layouts and that's why activity restarts (calls onC`onCreate()`). You can save your instance with overriding this method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and restore instance with overriding this method:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I created source in github about this topic, saving instances and restoring. Maybe it'll help you in some circumstances. [Orientation Mode](https://github.com/JavadBadirkhanli/orientation-mode)